# Maven - how to rebuild .xml files only on a Java EE project

Tags: java, maven

As the title states.
I've made changes to .xml file only. Do I need to `mvn clean install` the whole project or a simple `mvn install`? Or maybe `mvn generate-sources` will do the stuff?
Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Depends on which XML files and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hibernate mapping .xml files. For model mapping. I do have a formula statement in .xml that have changed.

Comment: And what are you trying to do? Re-compile your project? Build a new artifact? Build a new artifact and install it in your local repository?

Comment: Generate .war file to be uploaded to the server.

Comment: `mvn package` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the artifact, you need to call `mvn package`. If you do not do a clean, beware that remainders of the previous build might still exist. Changing the code of a class is generally fine, while changing the dependencies in the POM is not (you might end up with both versions of an artifact if you change the version in the POM).

Your hibernate case is somewhere in between, so you probably need to make experiments. Maven does not make any guarantees.